# Trying to run 4 Junit tests in Android Studio, but one of the tests runs 3 times instead

Tags: android, junit, android-studio

Here is my code:

```
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

import junit.framework.*;

public class ParametrizedStaticMapsRequestTest extends TestCase {

    @SmallTest
    public void testParametrizedStaticMapsRequest() {

        ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest mapsRequest = new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.Builder()
                .centerValue(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.LatLngPoint(42.7000, 23.3333))
                .imageFormat(ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsImageFormat.JPG)
                .size(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.SizeInPixels(320, 150))
                .zoomLevel(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsZoomLevel(15))
                .build();

        System.out.println(mapsRequest.toString());
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testParametrizedStaticMapsRequestThrowingExceptionWithInvalidLatLng() {

        try{
            ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest mapsRequest = new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.Builder()
                    .centerValue(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.LatLngPoint(422.7000, 233.3333))
                    .imageFormat(ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsImageFormat.JPG)
                    .size(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.SizeInPixels(320, 150))
                    .zoomLevel(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsZoomLevel(15))
                    .build();
            Assert.fail("Should have thrown IllegalArgumentException");
            System.out.println(mapsRequest.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // Success
        }
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testParametrizedStaticMapsRequestThrowingExceptionWithNullLatLng() {
        try{
            ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest mapsRequest = new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.Builder()
                    .centerValue(null)
                    .imageFormat(ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsImageFormat.JPG)
                    .size(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.SizeInPixels(320, 150))
                    .zoomLevel(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsZoomLevel(15))
                    .build();
            Assert.fail("Should have thrown IllegalArgumentException");
            System.out.println(mapsRequest.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // Success
        }
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testParametrizedStaticMapsRequestThrowingExceptionWithNullImageFormat() {
        try{
            ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest mapsRequest = new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.Builder()
                    .centerValue(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.LatLngPoint(422.7000, 233.3333))
                    .imageFormat(null)
                    .size(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.SizeInPixels(320, 150))
                    .zoomLevel(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsZoomLevel(15))
                    .build();
            Assert.fail("Should have thrown IllegalArgumentException");
            System.out.println(mapsRequest.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // Success
        }
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testParametrizedStaticMapsRequestThrowingExceptionWithInvalidSize() {
        try{
            ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest mapsRequest = new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.Builder()
                    .centerValue(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.LatLngPoint(422.7000, 233.3333))
                    .imageFormat(ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsImageFormat.JPG)
                    .size(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.SizeInPixels(2, -23))
                    .zoomLevel(new ParametrizedStaticMapsRequest.GoogleMapsZoomLevel(15))
                    .build();
            Assert.fail("Should have thrown IllegalArgumentException");
            System.out.println(mapsRequest.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // Success
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the actual output:

```
LatLntPoint is mandatory and cannot be null
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIQ&center=42.7,23.3333&format=jpg&zoom=15&size=320x150
Latitude should be within -90.0 and 90.0
Latitude should be within -90.0 and 90.0
Latitude should be within -90.0 and 90.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the expected output:

```
LatLntPoint is mandatory and cannot be null
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIz_mORNS-0Q&center=42.7,23.3333&format=jpg&zoom=15&size=320x150
Latitude should be within -90.0 and 90.0
Image format should not be null
Size should be within 180 and 600

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exmple"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'


}
```

Comment: Why are you printing Junit tests? Why not `assert` the returned values?

Comment: I want to setup the system first

Comment: Post your build.gradle. I believe you are using an old Junit version.

Comment: Posted it in the question

Comment: Are you tests in `src/test`? Try not extending `TestCase` and you do not need those `@SmallTest` annotations, use `@Test`. Then try fixing one test at a time.

Comment: Removed annotations, same result. What should I extend instead of TestCase? My tests are in test.java.com.example and the code is in com.example

Comment: You are using Android Studio aren't you? You should be using the same package name, just under the `app/src/test` folder instead of `app/src/main`. **FIX** one test at a time. Assert the correct output for the first test.